# Can't I use an object to query in mongoose?

Tags: object, mongodb, node.js, criteria, mongoose

Ihave a problem when i use an object as criteria when querying in mongoose.

```
var id = {
    cid: 111,
    vid: 222,
    pid: 333
};

// the following doesn't work at all
Category.find({id: id}, function(err, docs) {
//----returns nothing.
});

// while
Category.find({'id.pid': id.pid, 'id.cid': id.cid,'id.vid': id.vid}, function(err, docs) {
//----returns some docs.
});
// does work`
```

Is this a problem or a feature?

Comment: After playing around with it for a while, I removed my answer. I can reproduce the issue, but was consistently confused by the results I found, both in the Node code and the Mongo console. My recommendation is to not use the objects as queries at all; they don't seem to be in docs.

Comment: @Isaac Cambron thanks for your answer,and i have one more question,if i don't use the objects as queries, should i create indices for 'id.cid' and 'id.pid' and 'id.pid'?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think querying with an object in that way (nested-object format) works with mongoose, because the underlying driver (mongo-node-native) doesn't support it yet.

If you are always querying on fields `id.cid`, `id.pid`, and `id.vid`, you should make a compound index over all of them - creating separate indexes for each one will not help as much, because the query can only use 1 index at a time during execution.